# Craft CMS 3 Date Field problem

Tags: craft3, datetime, fieldtypes

I added some date fields on my entry. I select a date and save the entry. 
But the date field saved the day before.

Every editing the entry continue saving the day before. When the date comes to the 27 October it stops.

İf I select before 27 Oct it's not a problem.

This video for the problem:
https://www.loom.com/share/82cb26be003540a9ae95e1f567ca0b18

Comment: Do the timezone in your control panel and on the server match?

Comment: For reference: https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/config/config-settings.html#timezone

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed that problem. I have changed timezone settings on the Control Panel. Actually I have to use `europe/ist` but this timezone give that problem. So I changed to `europe/kirov` and my problem was fixed.

Comment: Please mark your question as answered since you've figured out a solution to your problem. (Mark your Answer as the solution)